# Difference between Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes and UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes

Tags: c#, utf-8, character-encoding

Can someone please explain me what is the difference bet. Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes and UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes? Actually I am trying to convert a XML string into a stream object and what happens now is whenever I use this line:

```
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml));
```

it gives me an error "System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid character in the given encoding"

but when I use this line it works fine:

```
  **MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));**
```

Even though it seems to be UTF8 encoding in both cases how one works and the other does not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no `UTF8Encoding.Default` property.  When you write this, you're actually returning the base class static property, [`Encoding.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx), which is not UTF8 (it's the system's default ANSI code-page encoding).

As such, the two will return very different results - since `UTF8Encoding.Default` is actually `Encoding.Default`, you will return the same thing as if you use `ASCIIEncoding.Default` or any of the other `System.Text.Encoding` subclasses.

The proper way to use `UTF8Encoding` is with an instance you create, such as:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream((new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(xml));
```

The above should provide the same results as:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));
```

Comment: Edit "The property way to use UTF8Encoding" to be "The proper"... wouldn't let me edit it since it's only a 2 character change.

Comment: +1 to answer for exact question. @user972255 - please avoid string manipulation when creating XML - you likely face problems with encoding mismatch as soon as your XML contains non-ASCII characters. Using `XmlDocument`, `XDocument` or `XmlWriter` methods to save XML to `MemoryStream` will save you and users of your data some significant pain dealing with invalid XML files.