# How to properly create a SHA256 Hash?

Tags: c#, sha256

I am implementing SSO where I have to compute the SHA256 has of a string and I send the hash back to and endpoint where it authenicates the user.  I got SHA1 working by doing the following:

```
 var hash = SHA1.Create();
 var encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
 byte[] combined = encoder.GetBytes(encryptedTokenStr);
 hash.ComputeHash(combined);
 string delimitedHexHash = BitConverter.ToString(hash.Hash);
 string completedSha1Hash = delimitedHexHash.Replace("-", "");
```

But If I change the Hash Algorithm Type to `SHA256` and on the other sytem change the Hashing algorithm to `SHA256 Salted (Suffix)` Not sure if this is the same as `SHA256`?  The following code does not work properly, meaning it does not authenicate the user on the other side:

```
var hash = SHA256.Create();
var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] combined = encoder.GetBytes(encryptedTokenStr);
hash.ComputeHash(combined);
string delimitedHexHash = BitConverter.ToString(hash.Hash);
string completedSha1Hash = delimitedHexHash.Replace("-", "");
```

Comment: why are you using var encoder = new UTF8Encoding(); instead of var encoder = new ASCIIEncoding(); as in the first example. is it a typo or on purpose?

Comment: I saw an example using UTF8, so that is why. I actually am not sure which one to use.

Comment: They will produce the same results according to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994042/difference-between-encoding-utf8-getbytes-and-utf8encoding-default-getbytes#16994086

Answer (score 1):

SHA256 is not the same as "SHA256 Salted".

Well, technically, they are both SHA256, it's just the input the differs. When doing SHA256, you hash the data itself. When doing "salted" (doesn't matter which hash function you use), you first add some "salt" to the input (addition could be different, but most often it's just concatenation; "suffix" hints that the salt is added after the input), and then hash the resulting data.

More details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29

Comment: So in order to create a valid hash, I would need to know what is being used as the salt. Correct?

Comment: Yes, and the exact way they are combined with the data too.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution I use the following (copy and paste ready):

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public string ComputeHash(string plainText, byte[] salt = null)
    {
        int minSaltLength = 4;
        int maxSaltLength = 16;

        byte[] saltBytes = null;

        if (salt != null)
        {
            saltBytes = salt;
        }
        else
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int len = r.Next(minSaltLength, maxSaltLength);
            saltBytes = new byte[len];

            using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                rng.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);
            }
        }
        byte[] plainData = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        int plainLength = plainData.Length;
        int saltLength = saltBytes.Length;
        byte[] plainDataAndSalt = new byte[plainLength + saltLength];
        Array.Copy(plainData, 0, plainDataAndSalt, 0, plainLength);
        Array.Copy(saltBytes, 0, plainDataAndSalt, plainLength, saltLength);

        byte[] hashValue = null;

        using (SHA256Managed sha2 = new SHA256Managed())
        {
             hashValue = sha2.ComputeHash(plainDataAndSalt);
        }

        int hashLength = hashValue.Length;
        byte[] result = new byte[hashLength + saltLength];
        Array.Copy(hashValue, 0, result, 0, hashLength);
        Array.Copy(saltBytes, 0, result, hashLength, saltLength);

        return ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
    }
```

Solution to your question/problem:

```
string hash = hash.ComputeHash("your string");
```

Or if server provide salt string for you:

```
byte[] salt = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("server salt string in plaintext");
string hash = hash.ComputeHash("your string to hash", salt);
```

then return hash to the server.

Comment: If I know the hashed salt value that was used, how does that modify your code?  Basically from the other system, I will have the hashed password and the hashed salt

Comment: If you have *hashed* salt, you can't do a thing, You'll need to know plaintext of it.

Comment: if there is a hashed salt one should ask for the plaintext salt from the SSO supplier. If allowed to use it of course. Driveby login is normally not supported anywhere.

Comment: Sorry I forgot I changed my result to hex string, now I changed it to return a normal string.